# Creating a data frame with rows from one data frame that are not in another data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I've been struggling with creating a new data frame where rows from one data from excluding rows from another data frame are included.

i.e., I have my original data frame with 551 rows (21 columns). I needed cut this data in half, in terms of rows, randomly. For the first half, I used:

```
first_half<-original[sample(nrow(original),275),]
```

However, I don't know how I would go about and create a data frame for my second half. So far I've fiddled with `dplyr` package:

```
second_half<-anti_join(original, first_half)
```

Since original data contains 551 rows and the first half contains 275, the second half should contain 276. However, it returned a data frame containing 235 rows. What went wrong here?

Comment: Are you sure there aren't any duplicates rows?

Comment: Hi @Cath, there may be some duplicate rows - my data are a list of participants' responses to a scale, which contain Likert type data. Is it perhaps why I have experienced the problem?

Comment: that's very likely the reason why you get fewer rows than expected

Comment: Ah so I suspected. I know there were a few other great suggestions that worked, but is there a way to get around this by amending my code?

Answer (score 1):

Just try

```
#get sample indices for first half
firstHalfIndices <- sample(NROW(original),275) 
#remove them from all available indices to get second half
secondHalfIndices <- base::setdiff(1:NROW(original),firstHalfIndices)

first_half <- original[firstHalfIndices,]
second_half <- original[secondHalfIndices,]
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you very much. May I ask for a walkthrough of the codes? What does "base : : " do?

Comment: `base::` is a so called namespace-prefix. Sometimes, if you have multiple packages loaded, the packages contain functions that are also contained in other packages. They have the same name, but don't have the same functionality. You can specify which function of which package you want to use by typing the packagename with a double-":" in front of the function. Its just a convenience of securing choosing the right function. So `base::setdiff` tells you: take the function called `setdiff` from the package called `base`.

Comment: Ah! thank you for the explanation. And for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

You might try to correct the way of subsampling. For instance you can use this:

```
df0 <- data.frame(id = c(1:551), val = round(rnorm(551, 50, 15)))

selection <- sample(0:1, 551, TRUE) == 1

df1 <- df0[selection,]
df2 <- df0[!selection,]
```

Using your original code it will be the same as

```
library(dplyr)    
df2 <- anti_join(df0, df1)
```

**Remark:** I used the following aliases: `df0` for `original`, `df1` for `first_half` and `df2` for `second_half`.

**Appended** on comment of @Jonas
I don't think that the specific way of sampling is a problem. It is possible to replace

```
selection <- sample(0:1, 551, TRUE) == 1
```

with

```
selection <- logical(551)
selection[sample(551, size = round(551 / 2)] <- TRUE
```

see

```
table(selection)
```

Comment: `sample(0:1, 551, TRUE)` doesn't give equally weighted halfs, see `table(sample(0:1, 551, TRUE))`.

Comment: @Jonas Thank you for the comment. See the appended answer